# What would be the best way to embed a video in salesforce articles

Tags: integration, knowledge, articles, website-integration, video

I definitely feel the Customer support which is conducted online, creates a great opportunity for us to utilize a knowledge base to guide customers to solutions without the need to contact support.

A highly useful knowledge base starts with creating help content /articles that customers actually want to read. If We know exactly what questions are most common from our support queue we can create articles which are much better than the regular ones for those issues.

As Video-based learning is a more effective educational tool, We are trying to embed/integrate videos in knowledge articles.

Please suggest few best ways to include videos into articles.

Answer (score 7):

Click on `Setup | Customize | Knowledge | Settings | Check "Allow users to add external multimedia content to HTML in the standard editor"` to `'True'` - you can then use the WYSIWYG editor on Rich Text fields to "Embed Media" into a Knowledge Article. This allows pasting the iframe code from YouTube, Vimeo, Dailymotion and a number of other video sites.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, Thanks for the info. I have already used the native way of embedding the iframe from a youtube or vimeo player and it works for me. 
I am trying to find out better ways to showcase knowledge videos with video based products like Vidyard, Wistia, Viddler for analytics purpose.